# CodeIgniter Encryption Class - How do I?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a registration page using CI that works fine. However, I encoded the password using sha1 (see code snippet below), and now that I plan to create a login page, I need to check whether the password the user enters in the login page is the same as that password encoded using sha1 stored in the database. However, I just realized that sha1 is non-decodable.

So how do I use CI's encryption class to both encrypt and then decrypt this password for login purposes? Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

> function register_user($username, $password, $name, $email, $activation_code){
>
> ```
>  $sha1_password = sha1($password);  
>  $query_str = "INSERT INTO table_name (username, password, name, email, activation_code) >VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";    
>
>
> $this->db-query($query_str, array($username, $sha1_password, $name, $email, $activation_code));
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to decrypt the password, only comparing for equality. That is all that is necessary for user identification.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply Adrian. I'm new to this, but correct me if Im wrong: should I sha1 the login password and compare the two resultant hashes?

Comment: Yes thats what you should do. Also look into "Salting" the passwords so a rainbow table attack is not possible

Comment: @Adrian, thanks for confirming this and letting me know about salting. I've started searching for this, but I have not found any yet, so I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 0):

For encryption/decryption CodeIgniter provide the Encryption class : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

If you need to be able to retrieve the password, you should encrypt your password (reversible process) instead of hashing them (one-way) : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/203341/.
Anyway, you should use relevant hashing method to handle password. For instance Bcrypt http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing_with_bcrypt

Other good reading : http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/